# Print the number of values which have the special characters in them

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file like the one below. I want to check the second column and print the count of values which have some special characters in them.

```
101,aaa,d01
102,*&%,d02 
103,$%&,d03
104,###,d04
```

I tried with awk:

```
awk -F, '{if ($2 ~ (/^[$*&%#]+$/) count+1;} END {print count}' sample.txt
```

but it's not working. Is there any way other than awk to do it?

Comment: Could you also elaborate _what_ were you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to check whether that column value has special characters and if so i want that count also

Comment: Consider including that information in the question.  An example or two would also help.

Comment: In the above example i specified,/ is the special character

Comment: If you want people to be _able_ to help you out, you need to phrase your question better.  (1) What exactly are you trying to achieve, (2) Sample input, (3) Expected output, (4) Any attempts that you might have made to solve the problem.  Unfortunately, the question in it's current form leaves a lot to _imagine_ for the readers.  As such, one would hesitate to answer.  Even if one does, chances are that the interpretation would be different from what you expect.  Good luck.

Comment: okay..do u want more information to be posted? or it is understandable now?

Comment: @user64676 way more information. _way more_. you've missed all four points in devnull's list.

Comment: I have to reiterate that you missed devnull's list of things to improve. Other than that, you need `count++` or `count += 1` or `count = count + 1` instead of `count+1` which is just a pure statement (without assignment). There is also a missing closing parenthesis in the condition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You don't specify this in your question, but your `awk` approach is attempting to count those second fields that consist *entirely* of special characters so that's what my solutions are doing as well. If that's not what you want and instead you want to count the fields that simply contain at least one special character remove the `^` and `$` from the match operators.

1. awk:

   ```
   awk -F, '{if($2 ~ /^[$*&%#]+$/) cnt++;} END {print cnt}' sample.txt
   ```
2. Perl:

   ```
   perl -F, -lane '$cnt++ if $F[1]=~/^[\$*&%#]+$/; END{print $cnt}' sample.txt
   ```
3. grep (this one assumes there are always only 3 fields):

   ```
   grep -cP ',[\$*&%#]+,' sample.txt
   ```
4. Shell

   ```
   count=0;
   while IFS="," read one two three; do 
       [[ -z ${two##[\*&%\$#]*} ]] && let count++; 
   done < sample.txt; 
   echo $count
   ```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
awk -F, '{if ($2 ~ /[^:alnum:]/) l=length($2);print $0" "l}' sample.txt
101,aaa,d01 
102,*&%,d02 3
103,$%&,d03 3
104,###,d04 3
```

Prints each line the count of "special chars", here chars that are not alnum.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it's not clear *exactly* what you want to do, but you can fix the syntax of your approach thus:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^[$*&%#]+$/ { count++ } END {print count}' sample.txt
```